# Django models - field dependency

Tags: python, django, validation, model

How can I have field dependency?

Case 1: If boolean field `call_me` is set, then `telephone` must be set, else it should be blank

Case 2: If many to many field `category` (with values **sale**, **rent**) has one of the values as **sale**, then `price_sale` must be set, else it should be blank

Comment: Sounds like you have your models layout badly. Try normalizing your database schema.

Comment: What part of it seems incorrect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Case 1, you can validate that easily in the model's `clean` method:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class MyModel(models.Model):
     ...
     def clean(self):
         if self.call_me and not self.telephone.strip():
             raise ValidationError('Telephone is required')
```

For Case 2, M2M relationships are not added until *after* the model is saved, so using `clean` on your model won't work in this scenario. However, you can do this from the `clean` method of any `ModelForm` you use to edit this, be it in the admin or your own view.

However, having `category` as a M2M when the only possible values are "sale" and "rent", is poor design. Even then, "sale" and "rent" are mutually exclusive, so an M2M is inappropriate anyways (your model won't be experiencing both a "sale" and a "rent" at the same time ever).

As a result, it would be a better idea to have `category` be a `CharField` with `choices` consisting of "sale" and "rent". If you do it that way, you can then use your model's `clean` method in the same way as Case 1 for this as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply -- for Case 2, the `categories` can be sale, rent and/or vacation so I'm guessing I'd need to have the join table. How can I require at least one row in a M2M field? What about the dependency on case 2? (I'm pretty new to Python/Django)

Answer (score 1):

Case 1:

Don't do it like that, have a different table for telephone numbers and have a `ForeignKey` from the Person (I'm assuming it's a person) to the the telephone number. If you have more than one telephone number per person, do it the other way around, otherwise consider using a `OneToOne`.

Obviously you'll want the `ForeignKey` to be nullable. That way, the only way to have a telephone number is if the person provided one.

Case 2:

I don't understand your database design here, so I can't answer. You'll have to explain more - why do you need a `ManyToMany` here?